# Webmatrix email send function

Tags: function, razor, webmatrix

I fully understand how to post some details in a form to send an email, but I am hoping on creating some sort of function/job to do this instead.

How do I create a razor function to do this:

```
    // Send email
    WebMail.Send(to: customerEmail,
        subject: "Your property is now added",
        body: "Blah Blah Blah"
    );
```

Is a function even the best way to achieve this? I'm just trying to create reusable code.

I'll need to be able to trigger this in an "if" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a wrapper function (façade) around the WebMail class but since the WebMail class is already a façade around System.Net.Mail, there seems little point, in my opinion.